# US postcode validation in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, magento

I need to validate the postcode in a format:

*1 character 1 number after 1 character 1 number after 1 character 1 number*

likewise with the length of 6 characters.

Example `X1X1X1`

It would be better in Magento's `VarienForm` form validation is appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/([a-zA-Z]\d){3}/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nM2hE9/1)

- `/(` delimiter and capturing group
- `[a-zA-z]` match a single character present in the list below
- `\d` match any digit
- `{3}` limit it to 6 character *(as mentioned in the question)*

Comment: I guess most postcodes use capital letters. More ever `\d` matches a range of numerical characters in other languages.

Comment: I'm not sure about being capital letters all postcodes ... then I have to support something like this `x1X1X1` .. Also `\d` is exactly the same with `[0-9]` in the JavaScript *(as OP used it as a tag for his question)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shafizadeh Its working extraordinary.

Answer (score 1):

I guess from your example `X1X1X1` that your postcode have capital letters and digits from `0-9`. Keeping that in mind you can use something like this.

**Regex:** `([A-Z][0-9]){3}`

**Flags used:**

- `g` for global search.

**Explanation:**

- `[A-Z]` looks for a capital letter.
- `[0-9]` looks for a digit.
- `{3}` ensures that this pattern is repeated thrice matching `X1X1X1`.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kM0nV1/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi Noob, Thanks for the reply. But i have given just an example like 3 repeats. 

My Inputs may Be Like "A2B3C4" or "A9B8C7" but limit 6.

Comment: @Srihari: Yes I know and I just quoted it in my example. It does work for all the format you are trying to match.

Comment: @Srihari: I would like to know the range of characters and digits that will be considered valid. For example is `0` permitted in any code ?

Comment: Its not my requirement noob, It like this only thanks for the support noob.

Comment: Okay, if this works for you great. I just wanted to make it useful for others in case they have the same question.